# Filter cyclical relations

Tags: django, django-models

I have couple of models, `Data`, which contains different versions of some data and `Master`, which keeps track of all versions, and a current_version.
Like this:

```py
class Master(models.Model):
    current_version = models.OneToOneField('Object', related_name='+')

class Data(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey('Master', related_name='data')
```

I would like to get all instances of `Data` which are only a `current_version` of `Master`. As in:

Data.objects.filter(Q(master__current_version=???))

How do I construct such a filter?

Comment: Why is `current_version` referring to `'Object'`?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, should be `Data`.

Comment: It seems that `Data.objects.filter(id__in=Master.objects.all().values_list('current_version'))` does what I need. Is this it or is there a better/correct way?

Comment: Why did you set `related_name` to `+`. With a proper related name, it would just be `Data.objects.filter(related_name__isnull=False)`.

Comment: Just to understand, are you saying that the related_name would be null if it doesn't point to itself?

Comment: `related_name__isnull=False` means that if we take the relation in reverse we filter suh that only `Data`s that are referenced by a `Master` through `current_version` will be retained.

Comment: That works! I am pretty sure you expect that. I will add a reverse lookup name. Do you want to post this as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: I checked the resulting SQL query and it just Briliant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the `current_version` a related name (different from `'+'`), like:

```
class Master(models.Model):
    current_version = models.OneToOneField(
        'Data',
        related_name='current_version_master'
    )

class Data(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey('Master', related_name='data')
```

You can filter with:

```
Data.objects.filter(current_version_master__inull=False)
```

Here you thus check if the relation "in reverse" finds a `Master` object, if it does, we retain the `Data` object in the queryset.

Comment: Here is the SQL. `SELECT ... FROM "data" INNER JOIN "master" ON ("data"."id" = "master"."current_version_id") WHERE "master"."id" IS NOT NULL`